# React Axios Network Error

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Estou fazendo meu primeiro curso de react native com axios e encontrei problemas ao fazer chamadas get.
O codigo relevante é:
api.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://192.168.15.8:3333",
});

export default api;
```

index.js:

```
 async function loadIncidents() {
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if (total > 0 && incidents.length === total) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    const response = await api.get("incidents", {
      params: { page },
    });

    setIncidents([...incidents, ...response.data]);
    setTotal(response.headers["x-total-count"]);
    setPage(page + 1);
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

O erro é:

[image: Erro]

Comment: nessa parte `const response = await api.get("incidents", {` faltou a barra, exemplo `const response = await api.get("/incidents", {` porque se não coloca aponta para o endereço errado

Comment: Fiz isso que você falou, continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: e não dá para saber! infelizmente problema que não podemos reproduzir

Answer (score -1):

Verifique se o IP do seu servidor não foi alterado sem querer.

Quando estiver trabalhando com requisições, ou funções assíncronas (await) num geral, utilize sempre try{ ... } catch { ... } para tratar o erro:

```
async function loadIncidents() {
    if (loading) {
        return;
    }

    if (total > 0 && incidents.length === total) {
        return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    try {
        const response = await api.get("incidents", {
            params: { page },
        });

        setIncidents([...incidents, ...response.data]);
        setTotal(response.headers["x-total-count"]);
        setPage(page + 1);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro: ', err)
    }
    setLoading(false);
}
```

Dessa forma você pode exibir o erro de uma forma mais clara, e sem travar sua aplicação